# ng-bind-html directive does not work.

Tags: angularjs

I have register the angular-sanitize.js file on the page and also add the dependency ['ngSanitize'].
still binding does not work.Please help me. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

Html

```
Comment : <div ng-bind-html="comment"></div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("trackApp", ['ngSanitize']);
trackApp.controller('feedBackController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.comment = "<input type='text' ng-model='customer.comment'/>";
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to make your html as trusted html.

try this code

```
var app = angular.module("trackApp", ['ngSanitize']);
trackApp.controller('feedBackController', ['$scope','$sce' function ($scope,$sce) {
    $scope.comment = $sce.trustAsHtml("<input type='text' ng-model='customer.comment'/>");
}]);
```

See example of ng-bind-html    http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/4iCXho3P

Comment: With this i think the ng-model is not properly binded.

Comment: yes nada i think but this will show the textbox surely :)

Comment: Maybe is best use a directive compile with a factory to get/set data depend on the user case. But that solves the question anyway.